# Android google maps v2 change layout size

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have map view in small size with expand button. Expand button changes map layout size. Everything works, but when the mapview is being resizing it leaves black artifacts around it.
How to get rid of this artifacts. And if it is possible at all?

[image]

Comment: It's known bug in GLSurfaceView, read this: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639